# javascript - encodeUriComponent with exclamation mark?

Tags: javascript, query-string, special-characters, urlencode, encode

Native `encodeURIComponent` doesn't support encoding exclamation mark - `!` which I need to have in url's query param encoded properly..

node.js `querystring.stringify()` doesn't it as well..

is the only way to use custom function like - https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/url/urlencode.js#L30 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could re-define the native function to add that functionality.

Here's an example of extending `encodeURIComponent` to handle exclamation marks.

```js
// adds '!' to encodeURIComponent
~function () {
    var orig = window.encodeURIComponent;
    window.encodeURIComponent = function (str) {
        // calls the original function, and adds your
        // functionality to it
        return orig.call(window, str).replace(/!/g, '%21');
    };
}();

encodeURIComponent('!'); // %21
```

---

You could also add a new function, if you wanted the code to be shorter.
That's up to you, though.

```js
// separate function to add '!' to encodeURIComponent
// shorter then re-defining, but you have to call a different function
function encodeURIfix(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21');
}

encodeURIfix('!'); // %21
```

---

More examples of this can be found at [Mozilla's dev site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description)

Comment: yeah, I know that can override it, but thought ``querystring`` at least has this by default, anyway thanks! ;)

Comment: Yw. As for your original question, yes I think it's necessary to create a custom function.

Comment: Why doesn't the JavaScript function handle this properly? Erlang's URI encoder doesn't either!