# Mailchimp Facebook share URL doesn't redirect to correct URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, encode, mailchimp

I am trying to use providing a variable to Facebook share plugin in Mailchimp. I want to share this URL :

`https://www.example.com/#!/campaign/5577fc135257be030087f44b/landing`

I am using JavaScript so I encoded the URL with `encodeURIComponent(uri)` which enables me to use Facebook Share:

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%23!%2Fcampaign%2F555ee391c95a870300616317%2Flanding`

The Facebook Share Dialog shows up correctly. However it only shares `www.example.com`, the rest of the url has been stripped out.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: The hash part is only of client-side importance, and two different hashes don’t make two different URLs. If you want to share different pieces of content, then you need different unique URLs for them as well.

Comment: Using Facebook's sharer.php is not supported. Instead, consider using the Facebook JavaScript SDK to open the share dialog or feed dialog. Hashbang fragments are/should be supported by Facebook, so if it doesn't work in the share dialog, you can file a bug about it at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

2 pitfalls to be aware of here:

1. Surprisingly enough, Mailchimp's social share content blocks won't URL-encode your link when building the Share URL. So as you proposed, you need to URL-encode it yourself.
2. JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent` is not exactly what you want here, because [it will not escape the exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835737/javascript-encodeuricomponent-with-exclamation-mark) (`!`), as well as a few other characters that have special meaning in URLs (see [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description)). Replacing the `!` by `%21` in your link would make it work.

Sadly I haven't found a JavaScript library that does this URL-encoding reliably ([url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) doesn't), you'll probably want to replace the `!` manually.